# Bootstrap with Razor DropDownList

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I need to apply Bootstrap styling to a Razor @Html.DropDownList.

I have applied the `form-control` class to the control:

```
@Html.DropDownList("FacilityID", null, string.Empty, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

This correctly displays the select list using Bootstrap stylings.  The problem is that the selectable, sub-items on of the list are not styled.

In viewing the generated HTML source, the rendered options are un-styled:

```
<option value="1">Some Option</option>
```

Is there anyway to get Bootstrap to style the entire dropdown correctly in ASP.Net MVC5 Razor view?

Comment: Are you trying to style a select as [shown here](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/)?

Comment: I'm not using that component, I'm using native Bootstrap and I'm aiming for the look shown here: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns

Comment: As you can see from that link, the html is not a `<select>` containing `<option>` elements. You can't style these element because they are rendered by the operating system, not HTML. When you see styled options, its generally because a jquery plugin has been applied to the `<select>` which typicaly hides the `<select>` and replaces it with its own html

Comment: Just keep in mind that this alone means you will not be able to post back anything so its a bit pointless. The plugins generally handle the click event of the 'fake' options and updates the 'real' (but hidden) select value. If you want a functional but styled select, then look at the link in my fist comment - but there are plenty of other jquery select controls you can use.

Comment: Thanks for the help ... I have updated the answer.  I was originally working with bootstrap-select, but I was trying to keep the number of custom modifications to Bootstrap to a minimum.  However, in this case, this works and is simple enough.

Answer (score 8):

If it helps anyone ... I ended up going with the [bootstrap-select](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) component.

The Razor syntax is:

```
@Html.DropDownList("FacilityID", null, string.Empty, new { @class = "selectpicker" })
```

I didn't like the default gradient applied by Bootstrap to the `button` element this component generates, so I modified this in CSS to make it look like a regular Bootstrap `form-control` styled element:

```
.bootstrap-select > .btn {
  background-image: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's really simple just add the following to the end of the Razor `DropDown`:

```
,new { @class = "form-control" }  )
```